# How to set dynamic content to an element in ui binder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Hi I have this code fragment in ui binder:

```
<ui:with field='resources'
    type='com.example.Resources' />
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="innercontent">{resources.title}</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

The `resources.title` part does not work. How can I access the field called "resources" to set the content of the div? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="innercontent"><ui:text from="{resources.title}" /></div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```